# API return json aray object, Keys containing dots,spaces and % in it. How to rename or remove key from array?

Tags: php, json, mongodb

> The object API returning containing dots, spaces and % in it. How to remove or rename these keys.

```
array:61 [▼
"status" => 0
"NetRange" => "31.0.0.0 - 31.255.255.255"
"CIDR" => "31.0.0.0/8"
"OrgName" => "RIPE Network Coordination Centre"
"OrgId" => "RIPE"
"Address" => "P.O. Box 10096"
"City" => "Amsterdam"
"StateProv" => ""
"PostalCode" => "1001EB"
"Country" => "NL"
"Referral.Server" => "whois://whois.ripe.net"
"Org Abuse.Handle" => "ABUSE3850-ARIN"
"Org Abuse.Name" => "Abuse Contact"
"Org Abuse.Phone" => "+31205354444"
"Org Abuse.Email" => "abuse@ripe.net"
"Org Abuse.Ref" => "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE3850-ARIN"
"Org Tech.Handle" => "RNO29-ARIN"
"% Org Tech.Ref" => "https://whois.arin.net"
"inetnum" => "31.13.69.0 - 31.13.69.255"
"netname" => "IAD1"
"descr" => "Facebook"
"country" => "US"
"admin-c" => "RD4299-RIPE, PH4972-RIPE"
"tech-c" => "RD4299-RIPE, PH4972-RIPE"
"mnt-by" => "fb-neteng, fb-neteng"
"mnt-lower" => "fb-neteng"
"mnt-routes" => "fb-neteng"
"created" => "2014-06-11T18:46:37Z, 2011-04-11T18:49:50Z"
"last-modified" => "2014-06-11T18:46:37Z, 2013-08-14T15:49:58Z"
"source" => "RIPE, RIPE # Filtered"
"role" => "RIPE DBM"
"address" => "1601 Willow Rd., Menlo Park, CA, 94025"
"nic-hdl" => "RD4299-RIPE"
"abuse-mailbox" => "domain@fb.com"
"% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.91.2 (ANGUS)" => ""
"cidr_mask" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Like change key **Org Abuse.Handle** to OrgAbuseHandle and **% Org Tech.Ref** to OrgTechRef.

Comment: The same way you would any other key, I would guess. You should be able to access those keys normally, so set a new key and unset the old one.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the code that isn't working we could tell you why.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'm using mongodb and their are some restriction on insertion if field contain ., $, % so I want to rename it before insertion or remove it if key containing dots or any special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this with the help of [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

**Steps:**

**1.** First of all get the keys from the array using `array_keys()`

**2.** Then modify the keys by replacing the unwanted characters like `%`, `.` `-` and  using `array_map()` and `str_replace()`

**3.** Finally combine the modified keys with existing values to make resulted array `$result`

```
<?php
$array = [
          "nic.hdl" => "RD4299-RIPE",
          "abuse-mailbox" => "domain@fb.com",
          "% This query was served by the RIPE" => ""
         ];

// replacing unwanted characters from every key
function replace_characters($n)
{
    return str_replace(array('-', ' ', '.','%'), '', $n);;
}

$keys = array_keys($array);
$proper_keys = array_map("replace_characters", $keys);
$result = array_combine($proper_keys,$array); // combine modified key & value
print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**SEE DEMO** : https://eval.in/999435

Comment: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'replace_characters' not found or invalid function name

Comment: Have you seen the demo it is working as expected, I think for your case the `replace_characters()` is not found

Comment: My problem solve by minor changes in it: `$proper_keys =array_map(function ($n){return str_replace(array('-', ' ', '.','%'), '',$n);},$keys);`